# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError for using org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: hibernate, spring

I've just started using hibernate annotations for my POJO mappings in my Sping+Hibernate based project (JDK 1.6.0_23) and I'm getting this error regarding incompatibility between classes. 
The sessionFactory is configured as:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="namingStrategy">
      <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">no</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">3</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.AtomikosJTATransactionFactory </prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my Maven project file I've set the following dependencies:


         

        
            javax.persistence
            persistence-api
            1.0
            jar
            false
        
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-annotations
            ${hibernate.version}
            jar
            false
        
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-core
            ${hibernate.version}
            jar
            false
        
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-ehcache
            ${hibernate.version}
            jar
            false
        
    
        2.5.5
        3.5.6-Final
        0.5

Could anyone give me a hint as to how to solve the problem?
Thank you

Peter

Comment: I've just fixed the problem. It seems that one of the other project dependencies (naming 'transactions-essentials-all' from atomicos) introduced hibernate core 3.2.5.ga in the deployment. I've wrote a nested exclusions with that dependency and all worked wanders cool stuff

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but you can find the answers here : [What is a IncompatibleClassChangeError exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534854/what-is-a-incompatibleclasschangeerror-exception-in-java)

Comment: Yeah, you could spend hours digging on that hint, since it is too generic. No use. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

it could be due to older version of hibernate entity manager or hibernate annotation, which is not match if you use newest hibernate core jar.
check both jars and try to upgrade it to newest version 3.5.x