# IncompatibleClassChangeError while creating bean sessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I was following the tutorial of [level up](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/getting-started/index.php). I type all the things in there. but some how getting exception.

I'm using tomcat 7 and jre 7

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
   </param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 </listener-class>
```

```
 <!-- Register a servlet that despatches requests to registered controllers  -->
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>world</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <!--  Send all .html files to the Spring dispatcher servlet -->
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>world</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Define the web application entry point -->
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>countryList.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

hibernateDataAccessContext

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

     <!-- Auto-detect the DAOs -->
     <context:component-scan base-package="levelup.world.dao.hibernate"/>

     <context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

     <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:maxActive="${dbcp.maxActive}"
        p:maxIdle="${dbcp.maxIdle}"
        p:maxWait="${dbcp.maxWait}"
     />


     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:configurationClass="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"
        p:packagesToScan="levelup.world.domain">
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
      <map>
        <entry key="merge">
          <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>

  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

  <bean id="txnManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>


  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

and Im getting exceptions :

```
       Jan 11, 2012 8:52:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:818)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
    ... 35 more
```

Any kind of help is appreciated .
    Edit:

```
List of Jars : 

antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
classmate-0.5.4.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar  
hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.7.ga.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-4.8.1.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.RC1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RC1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-modules-validation-0.8.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534854/what-is-a-incompatibleclasschangeerror-exception-in-java. It must be a problem with the classpath.

Comment: classpath, how ?? please don't mind, I didn't get it ..

Comment: You probably have conflicting versions of libraries (jar files) in your classpath.

Comment: added the list of jars. can you please check it for me ?

Comment: annotations are in Hibernate core now. You don't need hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar. And your spring context uses hibernate3 classes, but you have hibernate4 in the classpath.

Comment: hey thanks a lot... so what do you suggest me ? do i need to add hibernate3?? or what is alternative in hibernate4?? I mean I didn't find the org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in hibernate4 ..

Comment: You must use http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html Read its javadoc: it's a replacement for AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6642/discussion-between-rokonoid-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 2):

You have incompatible versions of hibernate jars.
And also you are using hibernate 3 to create your session factory whereas all your hibernate jars are hibernate 4 jars.

I'll suggest you a list of hibernate jars that should work out pretty well in your case:

```
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-c3p0-3.3.1.GA.jar
hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-core.jar
```

Comment: Thanks @Anvay .. I think it will help a lot.