# what is this error in eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

when i want to open java file to edit I get this error

```
Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized.
```

error details

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.getTypeReference(SourceElementParser.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeEnterVariable(Parser.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:5360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9368)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9605)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9562)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(BecomeWorkingCopyOperation.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.becomeWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4050)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2578)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3037)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3055)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3082)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2860)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: i found this .. "Recompile the client code against the new library, and you should be good to go." but i don't know how to do it ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug in JDT. Does this happen on a specific java file?

Please file a bug report here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT