# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError in Apache POI while running in Oracle Agile 9.3.0.2 for Linux

Tags: java, oracle11g, apache-poi

I am building a Java Px in Oracle Agile 9.3.0.2.

My Px involves interaction with Excel files of both formats (HSSF and XSSF).

I am using Apache POI library for excel file processing.

But i get **"java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError"** for this line :

**Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(ip);**

where **ip** is the input stream of the excel file.

when i try to access any HSSF spreadsheet file. **(.xls)**

The Px works fine for XSSF spreadsheet files. **(.xlsx)**

Please help!!!!

Comment: have you looked at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a fairly good chance that you have two different copies of Apache POI on your classpath. You need to ensure that all your POI jars (normal, scratchpad, ooxml etc) are from the same version. See the [POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for how you can check what jar file is actually being used in production.

Comment: I have checked every possibility of that but no result.

Comment: Did you try the code that the FAQ suggests? You'd be surprised how many people that solves the issue for - a jar they didn't realise is usually the culprit..

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if there are any `poi-*.jar` files bundled in the application server itself? If there are any, it can cause similar problems. Maybe do a search with TotalCommander in compressed files as well for `Workbook.class` or `WorkbookFactory.class` to ensure these classes cannot be found in any other jars..