# interface exception

Tags: java, class, exception, interface

i have these codes

```
    UserAgentContext uAgent=new SimpleUserAgentContext();
    DocumentBuilderImpl docBuild=new DocumentBuilderImpl(uAgent);
    docBuild.parse(new InputSourceImpl("http://dic.amdz.com/"));
```

when i run , it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface sun.font.FontManager, but class was expected
    at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont(FontFactory.java:210)
    at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont_Impl(FontFactory.java:180)
    at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont(FontFactory.java:127)
    at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.java:98)
    at org.lobobrowser.html.style.StyleSheetRenderState.<clinit>(StyleSheetRenderState.java:43)
    at org.lobobrowser.html.domimpl.NodeImpl.<clinit>(NodeImpl.java:39)
    at org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl.createDocument(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:143)
    at org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:97)
    at cobratest2.Cobratest2.main(Cobratest2.java:21)
```

then pointing me to the last line. so the question is, what to do?

Comment: The same post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: @lonesome: it's a stack of method called before exception occured. if you want to know deeper: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

Comment: @Azodious well i read the link, my program is totally that 3 lines. i dont think if there is any of the explained ways in the link that would work with it...

Comment: @e-zincu gotta be joking,,, same post? i didnt see any similarity

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at

```
org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont(FontFactory.java:210)
```

That class was compiled against an old version of the libraries in which`sun.font.FontManager` was a class, but you are trying to run it with newer libraries in which it is now an interface.  You will probably have to recompile all of the `org.lobobrowser` package against current libraries.

And BTW, the link [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452) mentioned by e-zinc does contain all the information you need to have figured this out yourself.

Comment: but the thing made me confuse is that i using the library of last version with the same version of documentation,,,so it shouldnt be changed, i just cant get it why it has changed, cause i just added the library and followed the documents to code my program

Comment: This could happen if the `org.logobrowser` library was built against an earlier version of Java than the program that uses it.