# Error while executing program with Hive JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I have written this small program for Hive JDBC. Initially it is executing fine but when I tried to run now suddenly I got error.

### Program:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class SampleHiveProgram
{
    String lyear="";
    String lquarter="";
    String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SampleHiveProgram s=new SampleHiveProgram();
        s.startHiveThriftServer();
        s.quarterTable();
    }

    public void startHiveThriftServer()
    {
        try
        {   
            String cmd = "/home/hadoop/sqoop-1.3.0-cdh3u1/bin/StartHiveThriftServer.sh"; // this is the command to execute in the Unix shell           
            // create a process for the shell
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", cmd);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // use this to capture messages sent to stderr
            Process shell = pb.start();
            InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream(); // this captures the output from the command
            // wait for the shell to finish and get the return code
            // at this point you can process the output issued by the command
            // for instance, this reads the output and writes it to System.out:
            int c;
            while ((c = shellIn.read()) != -1)
            {
                System.out.write(c);
            }
            int shellExitStatus = shell.waitFor();
            // close the stream
            shellIn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void quarterTable()
    {
        try
        {
            String start="2010-01-01";
            String end="2011-01-01";
            System.out.println("in quarter table...");
            //create connection with database
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
            String sql=null;
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res=null;

            sql="drop table TmpQuarterTable";
            System.out.println("Dropping the Quarter Table...");
            res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Creating Quarter Table
            sql="create table TmpQuarterTable (year string, quarter string, quarterstart string, quarterend string, quartername string)" +
                " ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE ";
            System.out.println("Creating the Quarter Table...");
            res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //create the file
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("/home/hadoop/Quarter.txt");

            //convert string date to calendar date
            DateFormat formatter =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date sdate=(Date)formatter.parse(start);
            Date edate=(Date)formatter.parse(end);

            Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();

            c1.setTime(sdate);
            c2.setTime(edate);

            int q=0;
            String QuarterEndDate=null;
            int resultMonthCount=0;
            int resultYear =0;
            int resultMonth =0;

            Calendar c3=Calendar.getInstance();
            c3.setTime(c1.getTime());     
            while(c3.compareTo(c2)<=0)
            {
                      if(c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)>=0 && c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)<=2)
                      {
                          q=1;
                          QuarterEndDate=Integer.toString(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-04-01";
                      }
                      else if(c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)>=3 && c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)<=5)
                      {
                          q=2;
                          QuarterEndDate=Integer.toString(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-07-01";
                      }
                      else if(c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)>=6 && c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)<=8)
                      {
                          q=3;
                          QuarterEndDate=Integer.toString(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-10-01";
                      }
                      else if(c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)>=9 && c3.get(Calendar.MONTH)<=11)
                      {
                          q=4;
                          QuarterEndDate=Integer.toString(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1)+"-01-01";
                      }
                      //Got the QuarterEndDate (YYYY-MM-DD)
                      //split the QuarterEndDate into qdate and create quarter_end_date
                      String[] qdate=QuarterEndDate.split("-");
                      Calendar quarter_end_date=Calendar.getInstance();
                      quarter_end_date.set(Integer.parseInt(qdate[0]),Integer.parseInt(qdate[1]),Integer.parseInt(qdate[2]));
                      System.out.println("quarter_end_date : "+quarter_end_date);

                      //YY
                      String YY=Integer.toString(c3.get(Calendar.YEAR));

                      //quarter start date = quarter end date - 1
                      Calendar quarter_start_date=Calendar.getInstance();
                      quarter_start_date.set(quarter_end_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),quarter_end_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),quarter_end_date.get(Calendar.DATE));
                      quarter_start_date.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

                      //year
                      String year=Integer.toString(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                      System.out.println("year : "+year);

                      //month
                      String months=null;
                      if(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)<10)
                          months="0"+Integer.toString(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                      else
                          months=Integer.toString(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                      System.out.println("month : "+months);

                      //day
                      String day=null;
                      if(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.DATE)<10)
                          day="0"+Integer.toString(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.DATE));
                      else
                          day=Integer.toString(quarter_start_date.get(Calendar.DATE));
                      System.out.println("day : "+day);


                      //adding 3 months
                      resultMonthCount = c3.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 3;
                      resultYear =  c3.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                      resultMonth = resultMonthCount - resultYear * 12;

                      System.out.println("YEAR : "+resultYear);
                      c3.set(Calendar.YEAR, resultYear);

                      System.out.println("MONTH : "+resultMonthCount);
                      c3.set(Calendar.MONTH, resultMonthCount);    
                      System.out.println("c3 : "+c3.getTime());

                      //YY,q,startDate,endDate,quartername   ------->>   write to file
                      String QuarterStartDate=year+"-"+months+"-"+day;                 
                      String quarterName=YY+"\"Q\""+q;                 
                      fw.write(YY+","+q+","+QuarterStartDate+","+QuarterEndDate+","+quarterName+"\n");

            }//end of while
            fw.close();

            String filepath = "/home/hadoop/Quarter.txt";
            sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' overwrite into table TmpQuarterTable";
            System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

The error is like:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client has interface org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient as super class

### Error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client has interface org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at SampleHiveProgram.quarterTable(SampleHiveProgram.java:64)
    at SampleHiveProgram.main(SampleHiveProgram.java:22)
```

What is wrong with me? I have added all jars required for Hive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By any chance do you have more than different versions of thrift and libthrift hanging around? It sounds like the classes are being generated with one version of thrift, but trying to use a different version of libthrift at runtime.

Comment: I got this too - make sure your libthrift version is the same as your libfb303 jar version!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error when I was trying run a sample **JDBC** against **HIVE**. I then added the location of **libfb*.jar** to the classpath & it worked fine for me. What I've learnt from the JDBC execution is that it requires a whole load of jar files which need to be explicitly mentioned in the classpath. My classpath looked something like this (the last few jars are absolutely required for the JDBC to execute)

```
[cloudera@quickstart ownjava]$ echo $CLASSPATH
/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/usr/lib/hive/lib/:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-0.12.0-cdh5.1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-service.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-service-0.12.0-cdh5.1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-metastore.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-metastore-0.12.0-cdh5.1.0.jar:/home/cloudera/ownjava/:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.12.0-cdh5.1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/libfb303-0.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
```