# Oozie hive action fails

Tags: hive, oozie

I am creating oozie workflow for hive create table command.

I have added hive-site.xml in hdfs location. 
I am getting below error:-

---

Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], main() threw exception, com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are missing Thrift jar or version mismatch.

Refer the following 
[Error while executing program with Hive JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328419/error-while-executing-program-with-hive-jdbc)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I checked the jar files that are present: libfb303-0.9.0.jar and 
libthrift-0.9.0.jar. How do i verify version mismatch?

Comment: simple way is to vim the jar and search for  the class com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface . The jar containing this class is the one you need to use

Comment: My job.properties file is as below:-
nameNode=hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020

jobTracker=sandbox.hortonworks.com:8050

workflowRoot=${nameNode}/root/ozzie_test
oozie.wf.application.path = ${nameNode}/root/ozzie_test

oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib/

oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath =${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib/

Comment: compare those hive lib jars in /user/oozie/share/lib/hive/ and those in your hive_home/lib/ folders

Comment: they are same, facing similar kind of issue in running sqoop action too.

Comment: Hi It worked now, I had not mentioned the namenode url before the script path in workflow.xml. job properties variable ${nameNode} was missing in workflow.xml