# Uncaught expection while accesing rest webservice from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs

I am referring [this](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.in/2010/02/create-and-deploy-jax-rs-rest-service.html) tutorial for creating rest webservice and deploying in GAE. This tutorial is works fine and I am able to run locally without any problem. Even I am able to deploy in GAE successfully. But when I am trying to access the url, I am getting following error

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request.
>
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

and GAE log contains this message

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at
>   com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-78db28d34b15c040(Request.java)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:452)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:458)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:698)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:336)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:328)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:456)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Please anyone let me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems jersey clashes with JDO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166382/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-deploying-to-app-engi

Comment: Thanks @PeterKnego. Let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as already mentioned above, this is due to an incompatibility between asm.3.1.jar and asm-4.0.jar. To resolve this problem, make sure that references to 4.0 are removed and you use Datanucelus API 1.0 since 2.0 needs 4.0 of asm.

I have written more in-depth about this issue here:

[Problems with GAE 1.7.2 and Jersey](http://cloudvane.com/2012/09/23/problem-with-google-appengine-and-jersey-with-java/)

Comment: Thanks but this link http://blog.harrywye.com/post/30160964741/running-java-jersey-with-jdo-3-0-on-google-app-engine solved my problem.