# Works locally but throws java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when deployed to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

I am attempting to use Jersey coupled with GAE to produce a RestFul endpoint.  The guide that I have attempted to follow can be found [here](http://blog.iparissa.com/googles-app-engine-java/google-app-engine-jax-rs-jersey/).  The service works properly when run locally.  When deployed to GAE I receive a 500 error with the stack trace shown below.

I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 1, AppEngine - 1.7.3, jersey-archive-1.1.5-ea-SNAPSHOT

Here is my Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.senseme.server</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>services</param-name>
      <param-value/>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>sensemeweb</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />

    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <!--
    HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:

      <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
    asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:

      <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />

    With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
    stale session data. For details, see
    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
  -->

</appengine-web-app>
```

Works locally but when deployed to GAE the following exception is thrown:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-eef9dd80521e7794(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:68)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:110)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:641)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:619)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:307)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I have tried just about everything to no avail,  How do I fix this?

Comment: After trying every possible solution I found this one to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13552626/778331

Answer (score 1):

After trying every solution I encountered this is the one that I found to resolve the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552626/778331