# struts2 on gae java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

It works good in eclipse with gae plugin, but when deploy to gae, I got the following exception.

I found there is a similar problem which happens in jersey, asm3.1 works against asm4.0, so I change datanucleus version to 1.x, and remove asm4.0.jar, but it still does not works...

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b07b8ce2cde74ee3(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:386)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:344)
at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been discussed over here: [java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class deploying to app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166382/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-deploying-to-app-engi). Please see if it helps.