# Jersey-based REST service at Google App Engine - how do I set up my project?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jersey

Have anyone made Jersey work at Google AppEngine with POJO Mapping to JSON?
I've been spending some hours on getting this working now, but I'm stuck at
two places. Running locally at Jetty I get one step further than at
AppEngine, but I'm not there yet either. Here are the two problems I am
encountering:

**Locally**:

Jetty produces the following error:

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class
nilsnett.chinese.backend.BusinessObject, and Java type class
nilsnett.chinese.backend.BusinessObject, and MIME media type
application/json was not found
```

`nilsnett.chinese.backend.BusinessObject` is a plain Java class I've created
that looks like this:

```
package nilsnett.chinese.backend;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
public class BusinessObject {
    public String text;
    public int value;
}
```

What is wrong here?

**At AppEngine**:

`Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError`

Now I had this error locally as well, and it's related to the fact that I'm
both referring `asm-3.3.1.jar`, which Jersey depends on, and `asm-4.0.jar,
which AppEngine depends on. If I _only_ referenced`asm-4.0.jar` locally, I
would get the same error here. Referencing both does obviously not work well
at AppEngine. How can I get around this?

**More data**:

- Full Jetty log of local error [here](http://pastebin.com/prKm23p2)
- Full exception log from AppEngine [here](http://pastebin.com/XTpwsvhN)
- [My web.xml](http://pastebin.com/YaEGuFEa)

SDK's referenced:

- AppEngine v1.7.4
- Java SE 1.6

Jar's relevant to Jersey referenced:

- Jersey-bundle-1.17.jar
- Asm-3.3.1.jar
- Jettison-1.1jar

I'm Developing in Eclipse Juno on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the `XmlRootElement` annotation but not using it. You should add `@XmlRootElement` ahead of your class.

As to the second issue - have you looked at:
[java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class deploying to app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166382/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-deploying-to-app-engi) ?

Comment: First issue: Did not help with `@XmlRootElement` (and it shall not be necessary). Second issue: Solved the problem - thanks! At least I can deploy now and get around the Json serialization using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, locally, was due to missing .jar files. I had misread the [Jersey documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) and thought I only needed the files listed under chapter [11.1 Core Server](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#core_server) and [11.4.3 JSON](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e1828):

- jettison-1.1.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.17.jar
- asm-3.3.1.jar

Turns out I also need the jar's listed under [JAXB](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e1718):

- jackson-core-asl.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl.jar
- jackson-jaxrs.jar
- jettison.jar
- jaxb-impl.jar
- jaxb-api.jar
- activation.jar
- stax-api.jar

I got fooled by the fact that the setup without the last jar's referenced worked when running in Glassfish, but that was due to the fact that the jar's come bundled with Glassfish. Not so with Jetty.