# Datanucleus plugin for app engine version problems

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have a problem with a GAE project; I am using Eclipse and GAE plugin for Eclipse.
I downloaded the last GAE SDK and I have also tried with some of the previous ones.

When I build a project I get this error in my Eclipse console:

```
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception
Please see the logs [C:\Users\ALESSA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\enhance7837945285064208066.log] for further information.
```

with the following log file

```
'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at      org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(ASMClassEnhancer.java:272)
at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:727)
at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
... 7 more'
```

In another question, someone suggested to change the Datanuclues JDO/JPA version used.
Originally it was the v2; then I changed to v1 and I continued to get an error. In particular:

```
An error occured for ClassEnhancer "ASM" when trying to call the method   "org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer" on class "getClassNameForFileName" : null java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I have the original GAE SDK with the default version of datanucleus and datanuclues appengine plugin

Comment: FWIW This is _Google_'s Eclipse plugin calling the enhancer, not any DataNucleus plugin. The DataNucleus project provides their own Eclipse plugin for such things but you aren't using that. So debug what is in the CLASSPATH for Google's plugin, and what the input is to their plugin

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769643/google-app-engine-datanucleus-3-1-1-unexpected-exception-error

Comment: I saw that question but I could not find a solution yet. @NeilStockton, I had not installed the DataNucleus plugin for Eclipse but also installing it I could not resolve the exception