# GoogleAppEngine Enhancer Error Code 1:

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I get the below error when attempting to compile my GoogleAppEngine Project. I am not to GoogleAppEngine and not sure where to look to resolve these generic sounds errors. Could not find good resources for resolving them myself. Please help if you can.

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_31 to compile java sources
Information:2/28/15 7:28 AM - Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 2 sec
        Error:Google AppEngine Enhancer: Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception
        Error:Google AppEngine Enhancer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
        at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.appengine.rt.EnhancerRunner.main(EnhancerRunner.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(ASMClassEnhancer.java:272)
      at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:727)
      at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
      at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
      ... 17 more
      Error:Google AppEngine Enhancer: Enhancement process terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: App Engine doesn't work with Java 1.8. Try doing it again, with Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Project SDK from 1.8 to 1.7 and worked.