# GAE throws Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError on server

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

i wrote some webservices that returns responce in JSON format, it works alright on local server but when i deploye over GAE it throws an exeption as blow

i am using GAE 1.9.26, java 1.17, jersey 1.17, asm 3.3.1.jar.

```
`Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-86e71008af5f499b(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:817)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Comment: This is similar to this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166382/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-deploying-to-app-engi/13552626#13552626> question