# Hibernate possible Maven dependency conflict

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I'm new to **Spring 3 and Hibernate 3**, and I'm trying to build a simple app to learn. But, if I try to execute it throws an Exception.

As far as I know it might be related to **maven dependencies conflict**, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the complete trace:

```
mar 05, 2015 2:17:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2452)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1264)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:818)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 35 more
```

Here are my `.xml` config files:

**config.properties**:

```
################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
#jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruhib
jdbc.username=root

################### Hibernate Configuration #########################
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

**app-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="es.sancas.prueba" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="Messages" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>es.sancas.prueba.bean.Usuario</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value> 
        </context-param> -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

And, finally, my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>es.sancas</groupId>
    <artifactId>prueba</artifactId>
    <name>prueba</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My database will have a table called `Usuario`, so here are the related classes:

The Usuario model class:

**es.sancas.prueba.bean.Usuario.java**:

```
package es.sancas.prueba.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    public Usuario(String nombre) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

My DAO Interface:

**es.sancas.prueba.dao.IUsuarioDAO.java**:

```
package es.sancas.prueba.dao;

import es.sancas.prueba.bean.Usuario;

public interface IUsuarioDAO {

    Usuario getUsuario(int id);

    int save(Usuario usuario);

    void update(Usuario usuario);

    void view(Usuario usuario);

    void delete(int id);
}
```

And it's implementation:

**es.sancas.prueba.dao.UsuarioDAO.java**:

```
package es.sancas.prueba.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import es.sancas.prueba.bean.Usuario;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UsuarioDAO implements IUsuarioDAO {

    @Autowired  
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuario(int id) {
        return (Usuario) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Usuario.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public int save(Usuario usuario) {
        return (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(usuario); 
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Usuario usuario) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(usuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void view(Usuario usuario) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(usuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        Usuario usuario = getUsuario(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(usuario);
    }

}
```

Let me know if I'm missing some info to show. Thanks!

P.S: I think it might be usefull if I post my **mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building prueba
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] es.sancas:prueba:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- (javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1.1)
[INFO] |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.0.1B)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.6)
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1_3)
[INFO] |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.2.15)
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 05 14:17:24 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/346M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474976/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-mongo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror ?

Comment: I did. I pick the idea from one of them to post my **mvn dependency:tree**, indeed. The point is that I don't know where to look (inside my project) to discover where the conflict is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution, but may not suit for everyone.

After many tries, I concluded that the weak point was the **session factory bean** in my `app-context.xml`, and tried to use Hibernate 4 instead (and use the latest Spring 3.x.x release). And it worked!

Here are the changes:

**app-context.xml**

```
<!-- ... -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>
<!-- ... -->
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<!-- ... -->
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.13.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<!-- ... -->

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency> -->

<!-- ... -->

    <!-- Common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- ... -->
```