# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: TextInputLayout.updatePasswordToggleView()

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm having a very disturbing experience where every instance of TextInputLayout crashes only in the release version of my app . Doesn't crash if I use AppCompatEditText. Doesn't crash in debug version.

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
    The method 'void android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updatePasswordToggleView()' 
    was expected to be of type direct but instead was found to be of type virtual
```

**XML-LAYOUT**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/pwdLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLayout"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/password"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"/>
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Any ideas what might be going on? Thank you.
I have gone from 27.1.1 to 26.1.1 support version and error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more easy:

- create a new clean project
- try it there and find out the the differences (there can be some incompatible options in the current project gradle files we wouldn't notice)

Good luck

Comment: by the way I tried your xml in the my project - it is working in the both configs )

Comment: I'm lost really. It just came up with this and it's shocking. Done several release builds with no issues and this just pops from nowhere. Creating it in a new project will just be crazy.

Comment: for that reason I always use some repository like SVN to keep different changes there and go back if needed )

Comment: Yeah I use gitlab. I'm trying all those out but it's simple fact that I haven't done anything about that layout or activity for several weeks now.

Comment: please check the com.android.support:support-compat version in the gradle and try to use the corresponding one

Comment: my be this helps us) :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797551/incompatibleclasschangeerror-interface-not-implemented