# I cant get hibernate working in my Spring Web Flow project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

I can't get hibernate working in my Spring Web Flow project. I keep getting sessionFactory working. Can someone please tell me why this is giving me a error

Here is my list of files in my project:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar
cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
files.txt
hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-3.0.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
icu4j-2.6.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar
joda-time-jsptags-1.0.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
list.txt
log4j-1.2.15.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.faces-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js.resources-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-remoting-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
tiles-api-2.1.3.jar
tiles-core-2.1.3.jar
tiles-jsp-2.1.3.jar
tiles-servlet-2.1.3.jar
urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

Here is my error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2716)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:818)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have incompatible versions of some of your JARs. Hard to tell which ones exactly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar` and `hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.jar`. That is way different. Try to use newer `hibernate ga`.