# Migrating to Spring 3.1 from 3.0.5 using apache-ivy: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven-2, spring-security, dependency-management

I'm struggling with Apache Ivy for the last two weeks to manage dependencies but the apparent ease of use which everybody talks about on the web (once maven/gradle/apache-ivy is used for DM) has eluded me. Can somebody please help and see what am I doing wrong? I'll really appreciate it.

I'm trying to use migrate an existing Spring/JPA-Hibernate application to the latest Spring and Hibernate distributions:

```
Spring 3.1.2
Spring Security 3.1.1
Hibernate 4.1
```

My Environment:

```
Eclipse Helios
Tomcat 7.23
```

ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">    <info
    organisation=""
    module="FocusIvy"
    status="integration">
</info>
<dependencies>  
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate.ejb" rev="4.1.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations" rev="3.4.0.GA-A" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate.common" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations.common" rev="4.1.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate" rev="4.1.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate.core" rev="4.1.0.Final" />
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator" rev="4.2.0.Final" /> 

    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.beans" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.context" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.context.support" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.transaction" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jdbc" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.expression" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />  
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.aop" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.web" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" /> 
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.web.servlet" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" /> 
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.orm" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="org.springframework.security.core" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" />      
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="org.springframework.security.aspects" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="org.springframework.security.taglibs" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="org.springframework.security.web" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="org.springframework.security.annotation" rev="2.0.6.RELEASE" />

    <dependency org="javax.activation" name="com.springsource.javax.activation"
            rev="1.1.1" />
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.cglib" name="com.springsource.net.sf.cglib" rev="2.2.0" />             
</dependencies> 
</ivy-module>
```

ivysettings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="defaultChain"
    defaultConflictManager="all" />

<resolvers>
    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
        <ivy
            pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <artifact
            pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>

    <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
        <ivy
            pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <artifact
            pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
    </url>
    <chain name="defaultChain" returnFirst="true">
        <resolver ref="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release" />
        <resolver ref="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external" />
    </chain>
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Tomcat server startup (and application deployment) results in a score of errors:

```
 WARNING: Unable to load class     [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossMCAdapter] to check against the     @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1988)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1951)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1840)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1808)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1794)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1214)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5148)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Oct 16, 2012 2:31:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
 WARNING: Unable to load class      [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossModulesAdapter] to check against   the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1988)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1951)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1840)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1808)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1794)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1214)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5148)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   Oct 16, 2012 2:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: Try using the Spring 3.1.1 jar instead.

Comment: Tried with 3.1.1. Same error.

Comment: First, The org.springframework.security.annotation has been repackaged to org.springframework.security.access.annotation and already included in core, so you do not need to add that.
Second, From version 3.5 hibernate-annotations is included with hibernate core, so you do not have to add it anymore. Also, is your web application is configured for Servlet 3.0?

Comment: @Ravi thanks for your comments, I removed the implicitly included dependencies, however, same error. About Servlet 3.0. I selected 3.0 for 'Dynamic web module version'. Also, the servlet has @ WebServlet annotation, which I think is only available for 3.0.

Comment: Did you check manually what all Spring jars are present in your application, also like this answer mark jsp-api and servlet-api with scope provided.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: Unable to load class     [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossMCAdapter] to check against the     @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class**

Sums it up perfectly **Apache Tomcat server is not a JBoss server**.

Secondly it appears to be reasonably a problem inside the spring framework so time to see which setting are needed for spring to load in Tomcat not JBoss