# SQLiteDatabase 'does not implement interface'

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, implements

Getting this error when I use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) as a [Closeable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html)

I've got a sample project to recreate it:

https://github.com/blundell/SQLDatabaseError

With a class that extends [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

....

public void openAndCloseDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

    close(database);
}

private void close(Closeable database) {
    try {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Oh no!", e);
    }
}

}
```

Stack trace:

```
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):   at com.blundell.sqldatabasecursorerror.DatabaseHelper.close(DatabaseHelper.java:35)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at com.blundell.sqldatabasecursorerror.DatabaseHelper.openAndCloseDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:29)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at com.blundell.sqldatabasecursorerror.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
12-14 12:23:43.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Closeable.html

This should work shouldn't it?

```
 public final class SQLiteDatabase extends SQLiteClosable
 >>
 public abstract class SQLiteClosable extends Object implements Closeable
 >>
 public interface Closeable
```

**Doesn't work:**

- Xperia Play Android 2.3.4
- Motorola Xoom Android 4.0.4

**Does work:**

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus Android 4.2

Comment: `public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Closeable` is possible too.

Comment: (not an Android developer) IncompatibleClassChangeError sounds like you're compiling and running against different versions of the library.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: @ignis and Anders: yeah, but those interfaces have been in there since API Level 1, and I would think that Android guarantees binary upwards compatibility. Weird...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, found the problem [in the Change Notes for 4.1 (API Level 16)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/16/changes/android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.html):

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable` implements `java.io.Closeable` only from API Level 16. Before that, they were unrelated (even though both interfaces existed since the beginning).

So you should use SQLiteClosable directly if you want your code to be backwards compatible.

It is also probably worthwhile to install the SDK for the lowest version you want to support and try to build with it, then this would have been detected by the compiler.

Comment: Would be nice if this was noted in the Javadoc for SQLiteClosable somewhere, too.

Comment: Thanks, good spot! Shame it's from api16 more safety check code to write. Yeah Lint normally catches obvious API level reqs, but as you say they are both available from API 1. Might create a Lint warning and push it up.

Comment: Just been bitten by this again! This time with `java.util.Scanner` http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/19/changes/java.util.Scanner.html

Comment: How come Lint API checker didn't catch this?