# Error while trying to open java file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I imported a new project(JAVA), and when tried to open the java files a pop up comes in eclipse saying

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

I tried to restart and switch workspace but in vain. It was working fine till yesterday.

Whats happening here?

Comment: Google: Showing results for [java.lang. *IncompatibleClassChangeError*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=4cd&rls=org.mozilla:zh-TW:official&q=java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError&spell=1&sa=X&ei=ctLTUYmwB8G-lQXP6IHoBQ&ved=0CCsQvwUoAA&biw=1440&bih=771) No results found for **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeEditor**

Comment: sorry about that it was a typo editied it now

Comment: See [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1980452/2040040)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some incompatible binary changes to the library. I think you are editing binary which is backward compatible. Did you clean the project and built all .class files?