# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java

```
package com.em;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class EntityManagerClass {
     public static EntityManager createEntity() {
         System.out.println("EntityManager start");
        **EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("idata");**
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("EntityManager"+entityManager);
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

Hi i am new to java .
When i am using  ENTITYMANAGERFACTORY in JPA,i am getting error like "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class".
please  help to solve this.

Comment: did you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: no, i didn't get solution.