# cxf rest spring service giving error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I am trying to expose rest service using **cxf rest**. i have **cxf 2.7.5** and **spring 3.1.3.RELEASE**  when trying to use the url `http://localhost:8080/web/services/rest/getreq` its giving error.

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2013 12:51:02 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:169)
    ... 42 more
```

i made my service class **@service("dimRequirementManager")** then is it necessary to create bean in cxf-servlet.xml?

**cxf-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">    
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />    
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    <bean id="dimRequirementDao"
        class="com.vxl.dao.hibernate.DimRequirementDaoHibernate">
    </bean>    
    <bean id="dimRequirementManager"
        class="com.vxl.service.impl.DimRequirementManagerImpl">
        <property name="dimRequirementDao" ref="dimRequirementDao" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Add new endpoints for additional services you'd like to expose -->    
    <jaxrs:server address="/rest">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="dimRequirementManager" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="feed" value="application/atom+xml" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    </jaxrs:server>    
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext-dca.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**service class**

```
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Service("dimRequirementManager")
public class DimRequirementManagerImpl implements DimRequirementManager {    
    DimRequirementDao dimRequirementDao;    
    @Override
    public List<DimRequirement> getAllByClientNIsCurrent(Long clientKey) {
        return dimRequirementDao.getAllByClientNIsCurrent(clientKey);
    }       
    @GET
    @Path("/getreq")
    public DimRequirement getreq(){
        DimRequirement requirement =new DimRequirement();
        requirement.setClientKey(22L);
        requirement.setClassification("classification");
        return requirement;         
    }
```

Comment: Could you verify if you have different version of the same libray(jar) in your classpath?

Comment: in pom.xml cxf version is 2.7.5. all cxf jar versions are same

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of conflict there is...
You can try to delete the `cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.1.jar`.
I don't know why, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I had my Spring context available inside the lib folder of my war and its transitive dependency such as cxf-rt-ws-policy, cxf-core was kept in tomcat lib folder. 
Moving cxf-rt-ws-policy and cxf-core to the war's lib folder solved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```