# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError while running POI 3.8 on Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, apache-poi, classloader

I’m having java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError error when I try to load jars in JVM on websphere and run my application. I’m using the following jars

•   poi-3.8.jar

•   poi-ooxml-3.8.jar

I have also checked manually for any different version used in lib folder but I couldn’t see any.
Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1980474/1283215

Comment: Thanx for sharing link, I tried the mentioned option which is again the parent last option but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have multiple jars with the same "package.Class" in different versions. The jars must not have 'same' name but different version. This exception rises, if the classloader loads the wrong class, that don't have an expected method par ex.

Probably this search helps you to find other jars that contain the same class. http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav

An other option could be, you set the classloader to PARENT_LAST. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzamy%2F50%2Fprogram%2Fclsadmcns.htm

Comment: I put all these jars in a seperate C: on the server and then mentioned the same path with all these libraries in the Websphere process difinition -> Java virtual machine. I dont see any other jar in that lib folder. I'm creating class path on server not on any specific application so I tried to change the "Server-specific Application Settings" class loader policy "Single" and Class loading mode "parent last" but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, Your problem resolved? I am also facing the same issue as you.