# Oracle Java: Error casting java.sql.Blob datatype to Oracle BLOB datatype

Tags: java, oracle, java-7, oracle12c

I am getting the following error upon executing Oracle Java procedure that accepts and returns BLOB data,

> Error report - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a return
>   value that is an instance of a user-defined Java class convertible to
>   an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted ORA-06512: at
>   "", line 86 ORA-06512: at line 7
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

**Java Code**

```
public static java.sql.Blob Convert_Image(java.sql.Blob srcBlob) {

java.sql.Blob desBlob = null;

try {
    Document document = new Document();

    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfDocumentOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter pdfDocumentWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfDocumentOutputStream);                        
    document.open();

    if (document.newPage()) {

        int indentation = 0;
        Image img = Image.getInstance(srcBlob.getBytes(1, (int) srcBlob.length()));
        float scaler = document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin() - indentation;
        img.scalePercent((scaler / img.getWidth()) * 100);

        document.newPage();
        document.add(Image.getInstance(img));
        document.close();

        desBlob = new SerialBlob(pdfDocumentOutputStream.toByteArray());

        pdfDocumentWriter.close();
        pdfDocumentOutputStream.close();

    }   
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Show_Message(e);
}

return desBlob;

}
```

**Oracle Code**

```
FUNCTION CONVERT_IMAGE(
    P_BLOB IN DOCUMENTS.BLOB_CONTENT%TYPE)
  RETURN BLOB
AS
  LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'egift.Util.Convert_Image (java.sql.Blob) return java.sql.Blob';
```

**Trigger Implementation**

```
...
DECLARE

    v_blob_content DOCUMENTS.BLOB_CONTENT%TYPE;

BEGIN

    IF :NEW.BLOB_CONTENT IS NOT NULL AND 
      (
        NVL(:NEW.MIME_TYPE,'#') = 'image/png' OR 
        NVL(:NEW.MIME_TYPE,'#') = 'image/jpeg' OR 
        NVL(:NEW.MIME_TYPE,'#') = 'image/gif' OR
        NVL(:NEW.MIME_TYPE,'#') = 'image/tiff' OR
        NVL(:NEW.MIME_TYPE,'#') = 'image/bmp'
      ) THEN
      v_blob_content := EGIFT_UTIL.CONVERT_IMAGE(:NEW.BLOB_CONTENT);
      IF v_blob_content is not null then
        :NEW.BLOB_CONTENT := v_blob_content;  
        :NEW.MIME_TYPE := 'application/pdf';
        :NEW.NAME := substr(:NEW.NAME,0,instr(:NEW.NAME,'.',-1)) || 'pdf';
      END IF;
    END IF;
...
```

Comment: None of the code shown will throw an exception with the error. Please show the actual code causing the error.

Comment: *FYI:* No need to use `Blob` is you're just going to use a byte array anyway. Use a byte array.

Comment: Please show the (complete) stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, it seems like everything is good but it's not as it's throwing a runtime error. I think Oracle is not able to cast return value of datatype java.sql.Blob to Oracle BLOB datatype. You mentioned about using a byte array, can you elaborate by providing an example.

Comment: @StephenC I have updated question with error and stacktrace.

Comment: @kapiell could you add java class with methods to serialize and deserailize default pdf objects explicitly as 
`public class BlobType{
private static Object deserialize(InputStream stream) throws Exception {

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(stream);
        //read pdf obj
        return ois.readObject(type:'%pdf');

      }
private static byte[] serialize(Object object) throws IOException {
//similar to your convert function
ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
obj.write(object);
return obj.getByteArray();
}
`

Comment: @kapiell - That's not a stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @kapiell, once I have problem converting Blob to java.sql.Blob. Instead of this class I used oracle.sql.BLOB. Unfortunately I don't have instance of Oracle to test the solution. Could I ask you to check it by yourself ?

Comment: @YevhenZhovtonoh I did try that approach but that class is deprecated and it won't let me use it.

Comment: which ojdbc version? are you free to upgrade? ...see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20072410/592355 ..first confusion for me (in regards to the error mesage) `oracle.sql.BLOB` (deprecated in newer versions(12+)) vs. `java.sql.Blob` [12.2.0.1 javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/oracle/sql/BLOB.html)

Comment: @YevhenZhovtonoh Thanks for your comment, I took another stab at it and modified my code to solve the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an instance of `oracle.sql.BLOB` or `oracle.jdbc2.Blob` from your Java procedure in order to create a trigger that calls the Java procedure and returns a BLOB. ORACLE actually has a table where they compare their datatypes to the Java instances they can accept:

[the legal data type mappings. Oracle Database converts between the SQL types and Java classes automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chsix.htm#BABJIJEB)

Update 1:
I actually tested passing java.sql.Blob and returning the same type in the function and it worked as expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Util" as
public class Util {
  public static java.sql.Blob Convert_Image(java.sql.Blob srcBlob) {

    return srcBlob;

    }
}
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_IMAGE(
    P_BLOB BLOB)
  RETURN BLOB
AS
  LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Util.Convert_Image (java.sql.Blob) return java.sql.Blob';


select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(convert_image(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('test'))) from dual;
-- test
```

Can you try to run the above code and see if you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution that I implemented since I was cutting close to my deadline, I am still in search of a solution wherein I don't have to use deprecated classes and would like to avoid reference of oracle.sql.BLOB and use java.sql.Blob.

Workaround involved creating a oracle.sql.BLOB object instead of SerialBlob and then populating bytearray from output stream as follows,

```
conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
desBlob = BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
desBlob.setBytes(1, pdfDocumentOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

And suppressed deprecation warnings using,

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

**Final Java Code**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static java.sql.Blob Convert_Image(java.sql.Blob srcBlob) {

    java.sql.Blob desBlob = null;

    try {
        Document document = new Document();

        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfDocumentOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter pdfDocumentWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfDocumentOutputStream);
        document.open();

        if (document.newPage()) {

            int indentation = 0;
            Image img = Image.getInstance(srcBlob.getBytes(1, (int) srcBlob.length()));
            float scaler =
                document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin() - indentation;
            img.scalePercent((scaler / img.getWidth()) * 100);

            document.newPage();
            document.add(Image.getInstance(img));
            document.close();

            //desBlob = new SerialBlob(pdfDocumentOutputStream.toByteArray());
            conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
            desBlob = BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
            desBlob.setBytes(1, pdfDocumentOutputStream.toByteArray());

            pdfDocumentWriter.close();
            pdfDocumentOutputStream.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Show_Message(e);
    }
    return desBlob;

}
```

I had setup a bounty to get a solution to resolve this issue w/o using deprecated class and I was unable to find one, although I received attention to this question. This is an open issue for me until I find the right solution. Thanks to all who made an effort.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution without deprecated code:

```
    public static Blob bytes2Blob(byte[] b) throws Exception {
        if (System.getProperty("oracle.server.version") != null) {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall ("{ call DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(?,true,DBMS_LOB.SESSION) }");
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BLOB);
            cStmt.execute();
            Blob blob = ((OracleCallableStatement)cStmt).getBLOB(1);
            cStmt.close();
            OutputStream out = blob.setBinaryStream(1L);
            out.write(b);
            out.flush();
            return blob;
        } else {
            return new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(b);
        }
```