# Return file as a blob from Oracle DB with java stored in DB

Tags: java, oracle

I want to read/write Blobs to the filesystem from inside the database without oracle directories, because I have a lot of directories and this makes it complicated.

I have java read/write rights on the main directory where we store the files. So security is no problem.

So I made a java function to read the file and encode it as a base64 string:

```
public static String getFile(String directory, String filename)
      {
        try {
            File file = new File(directory + "/" + filename);
            byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file", e);
        }
      }
```

This works fine with the following pl/sql function:

```
FUNCTION get_file (p_dir in varchar2, p_file in varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'FilesFromUnix.getFile (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

But what I want to do is not return it as a VARCHAR2 and a String but use it as a Blob instead, but when I try to do this like with this code snippet:

```
public static byte [] getFile2(String directory, String filename)
      {
        try {
            File file = new File(directory + "/" + filename);
            return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file", e);
        }
      }
```

I have a problem when trying to call it in a pl/sql function:

```
FUNCTION get_file2 (p_dir in varchar2, p_file in varchar2) RETURN BLOB
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'FilesFromUnix.getFile (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.lang.Byte';
```

a return value that is convertible to an Oracle BLOB expected, a Java java.lang.String received

I also tried with the following snippet:

```
public static Blob getFile2(String directory, String filename)
  throws SerialException, SQLException
      {
        try {
            File file = new File(directory + "/" + filename);
            return new SerialBlob(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file", e);
        } catch (SerialException s) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file", s);
        } catch (SQLException f) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("could not read file", f);
        }
      }
```

But couldn't get it also returned in PL/SQL as a BLOB.

Do one of you know a way how to return the file as a BLOB in the pl/sql part ?

My files are binary files.

And they could be large also, so I don't wan't restrictions on size.

Comment: The [docs section on data type mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/defining-call-specifications.html#GUID-698850EA-53C0-42C3-84A3-9A590BB15123) says that BLOBs can't be mapped to byte arrays, and to use `oracle.sql.BLOB` instead. Have you tried returning that (or `java.sql.Blob`)?

Comment: If I use oracle.sql.BLOB it says it is deprecated.
And if I use java.sql.Blob it says it compiles, but when I try to run it, it says the java.sql.Blob can't be converted to oracle.sql.BLOB

Comment: I use now the oracle.sql.BLOB with a supress warning, but I like some code without a deprecated item inside

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I see [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488802/oracle-java-error-casting-java-sql-blob-datatype-to-oracle-blob-datatype) but no good answers. Maybe try [oracle.jdbc.OracleBlob](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleBlob.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution with java.sql.Blob, I probably made a mistake with my first try and mixed the types:

```
public static Blob getFile(String directory, String filename)
  throws SQLException, IOException
      {
            File file = new File(directory + "/" + filename);
            
            Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
            Blob desBlob = conn.createBlob();
            desBlob.setBytes(1, Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
            return desBlob;
      }
```

And the pl/sql procedure

```
FUNCTION get_file (p_dir in varchar2, p_file in varchar2) RETURN BLOB
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'FilesFromUnix.getFile (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.sql.Blob';
```

This works without deprecation.