# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to ApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml, spring, app-config

I am trying to convert an xml file using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to ApplicationContext and get a class change error every time.

ivy.xml:

```
<dependency org="cglib"               name="cglib"          rev="3.0"         conf="compile->master" /> 

<dependency org="spring"              name="spring-beans"   rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
<dependency org="spring"              name="spring-core"    rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
<dependency org="spring"              name="spring-jdbc"    rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
<dependency org="spring"              name="spring-tx"      rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
<dependency org="spring"              name="spring-test"    rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />

<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-asm"     rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" /> 
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop"     rev="3.0.4.RELEASE" conf="compile->master" />
```

java class line where breaks:

```
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationConfig.xml");
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at
```

(needed to remove paths and class names)

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I feel like I am missing a dependency or my versioning is off but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Tried the following:

Comment: ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContextXml = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ipsanalytic_applicationContext.xml");
   applicationContext = applicationContextXml;

Comment: It broke before assigning it to the ApplicationContext so maybe there is something wrong with my xml file.

Comment: Could you please share the complete import path of ApplicationContext ? I guess this could be wrong .

Comment: import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

Comment: No issues with import. Did you go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23095585/4214241) already ?

Comment: Yes, I only found two forums in here related to this, that the most informative, and I added that dependency. Also checked the maven repository to see if that had any dependencies as well.