# Java Eclipse : Hibernate Configuration to AnnotationConfiguration does not work and gives the runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

Recently, I created a Maven project in which I created the following files

1. Model Class
2. Calling Class ( Instantiates Model Class object and create Session factory)
3. Hibernate.cfg.xml file

   org.postgresql.Driver
           jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/dev
           temp
           temp
           
           1

   ```
       <!-- SQL Dialect -->
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

       <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping class="org.test.livejava.machine.UserDetails" />
   ```
4. Added the following dependencies in Maven.

   UTF-8

   JBoss repository
           http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
       


       
           junit
           junit
           3.8.1
           
       
       
           org.codehaus.mojo
           hibernate3-maven-plugin
           2.0
       
       
           org.slf4j
           slf4j-api
           1.7.6
           compile
       
       
           org.postgresql
           postgresql
           9.3-1100-jdbc41

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>javassist</groupId>
       <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
       <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Now, when I run the program and run it, it gives me the following error.

```
19:04:12,784  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.2.0.cr5
19:04:12,786  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
19:04:12,787  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
19:04:12,789  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
19:04:12,818  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
19:04:12,818  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="org.test.livejava.machine.UserDetails"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1479)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.test.livejava.machine.machine.main(machine.java:29)
```

After reading about the deprecated Configuration method, I used AnnotationsConfiguration() and it started giving me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.test.livejava.machine.machine.main(machine.java:29)
```

Has anyone got the same issue before while compiling? I am not sure why this is not able to find load it correctly even though all the maven dependencies seem to be included

I appreciate your time and help looking into it!

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a compile error.

Comment: @chrylis: [Seems like it could be.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1980452/1079354)

Comment: Sorry about that :(, I ran it and it is a run time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Maven dependency lists a Hibernate version of `3.6.3.Final`, but your logs indicate a Hibernate version of `3.2.0.cr5` (note that even if you need to stay with Hibernate 3, the bugfixes are up to 3.6.10).

The problem is attempting to use an ancient version of Hibernate at runtime: You either aren't using Maven to launch the program, or you're not compiling it into a fat war or jar.

Comment: Thank you for your time to look into it. I had changed my hibernate version from 3.6.3 Final to 4.0.1 Final version. Also, all the dependencies are correct in the pom.xml. I do not get this error anymore. Thanks again!