# CXF failing with IncompatibleClassChangeError exception on Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, maven, cxf

I have an application using **Spring-3.2.X** and **cxf-2.7.5**

I'm importing cxf into my spring's app context like so:

```xml
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:cxf.xml" />
```

However, When I run the tests I end up with the following exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:154)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:169)
    ... 56 more
```

From reading [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) it looks like `IncompatibleClassChangeError` - Means I probably have conflicting library versions on my classpath.  I can't tell from the stack trace which class/library is being duplicated.

My POM looks like so:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <properties>
    <wicket.version>1.5.11</wicket.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat60</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <bootClassPath>
      ${env.JRE_6_HOME}\lib\rt.jar;${env.JAVA_HOME}\lib\tools.jar;${env.JRE_6_HOME}\lib\jsse.jar;
    </bootClassPath>
    <toolsDir>${env.JAVA_HOME}\lib</toolsDir>
    <jsseDir>${env.JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib</jsseDir>
    <m2Repository>${env.USERPROFILE}/.m2/repository</m2Repository>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
       </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- shared look/functionality -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>us.ak.state.revenue.cssd</groupId>
      <artifactId>myAlaska</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
          <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>us.ak.state.revenue.cssd</groupId>
      <artifactId>doc</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
      <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
      <version>${wicket.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
          <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <!-- TODO: once unit tests work test if this should be test scoped -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Make Sure CXF starts properly -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Transactional Support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LDAP Authentication -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.novell.ldap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jldap</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PDF report Generation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- email -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsse</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0_21</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${env.JRE_6_HOME}\lib\jsse.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mainframe/Broker -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.softwareAG.entirex</groupId>
      <artifactId>entirex-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>9.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

      <!-- Unknown / Miscl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
         <compilerArguments>
           <bootclasspath>
             ${bootClassPath};
           </bootclasspath>
           <endorseddirs>
             ${m2Repository}/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.6/;${m2Repository}/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/2.7.5/;${toolsDir};${jsseDir};
           </endorseddirs>
         </compilerArguments>
          <compilerArgument> -Xlint:unchecked </compilerArgument>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
         <optimize>true</optimize>
         <debug>true</debug>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.2</version>
       <configuration>
         <!-- License info removed -->
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/SessionFactoryBean*.java</exclude>
         </excludes>
         <cloverDatabase>${project.basedir}/.clover/db</cloverDatabase>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>clover</id>
           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>instrument</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- moves the test results outside of clover-->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
         <reportsDirectory>
           ${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports
         </reportsDirectory>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>    

</project>
```

**MyAlaska** is a shared library that another project is successfully using,
with the following dependencies:

```xml
<!-- another shared jar sits here that pulls in Wicket,Look-feel stuff -->


<!-- ADFS attempt #2, this time with WS-Federation/SAML support -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-hc</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<!--https WS stuff-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-sso-saml</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- specifically adds SAML/federation to the stack -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf.fediz</groupId>
  <artifactId>fediz-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf.fediz</groupId>
  <artifactId>fediz-cxf</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf.fediz</groupId>
  <artifactId>fediz-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Security integration-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- configuration update "magic" -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you're still here, thanks for reading.
What am I doing wrong?
Why won't CXF/Spring start, and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**
After running the debugger the offending class appears to be:
`org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl`
which resides in **cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.5**
As far as I can tell though that's the only place for that jar and It's only included once.

**JHades Update**
When I initially ran the report Log4J and Log4J-extras were overlapping, so was
JavaMail-1.5 and geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec. I've resolved those uses.

report results:

```
>>>> Jar overlap report: 


Total number of classes with more than one version: 0
```

Both **Jhades** and `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true` inidicate that **cxf-rt-ws-policy** is **2.7.5** just like every other cxf jar version.

Comment: One of the possible way do diagnose this problem is run your program in debugger with breakpoint set on IncompatibleClassChangeError exception throwing and then examine local variables to find out which class cxf is trying to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I it turns out my IDE [intellij-dea](/questions/tagged/intellij-dea) was messing up my build.
I thought that since I had maven configured, that it would just be running pure maven, under the hood.
In my IDE I had configured an installed Directory for **Axis2-1.6.0** to be used before my maven dependencies.  Axis-2 was left over from an OLD version of my application and held duplicates of a lot dependencies including something called **Neethi**, which I've seen listed else where as a potential source of this error with **CXF**.

Comment: Use "maven dependency:tree" to find which dependency uses neethi, then exclude it this way :
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion><groupId>javax.servlet</groupId><artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId></exclusion>
    <exclusion><groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId><artifactId>neethi</artifactId></exclusion>
            </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: Re-verify `CXF` version in maven dependency and the one you added in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 3):

It seems the version of class `org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl` that is being loaded is invalid.

You can check the WAR to see if there are any duplicate classes using this command (from [JHades](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014155/http://jhades.org/), a tool I've made), see here for the [duplicate classes report](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305022648/http://jhades.org/documentation.html#warreport):

```
java -jar jhades-standalone-report.jar path/to/war/webapp.war
```

The report should give something like this:

```
>>>> Jar overlap report:

poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar overlaps with poi-3.7-20101029.jar - total overlapping classes: 990
xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar overlaps with xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 867
xalan-2.6.0.jar overlaps with xalan-2.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 711
bcel-5.2.jar overlaps with xalan-2.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 361
xml-apis-2.9.1.jar overlaps with xml-apis.jar - total overlapping classes: 301
jasperreports-applet-3.7.1.jar overlaps with jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 254
jasperreports-3.7.1.jar overlaps with jasperreports-applet-3.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 254
...

Total number of classes with more than one version: 6169
```

Also it's possible to query the classpath for all versions of the class and for the currently used version:

```
System.out.println("All versions of AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl:" + getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("org/apache/cxf/ws/policy/AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.class"));

System.out.println("Currently used version of AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl:" + getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/cxf/ws/policy/AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.class"));
```

There are a couple of possibilities: either multiple versions exist, and only one is correct. In that case exclude the jars with the wrong versions in maven.

If only one version exists, then it's the wrong one, use `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true` to find why it's included, and update the pom to load the correct version.

Comment: a tool called "TattleTale" does that same thing (from jboss)