# Eclipse ..... editor could not be initialized

Tags: eclipse

I was making android application project in eclipse.

I can't open java files in eclipse.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

editor could not be initialized
```

what I should do?

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror ?

Comment: This answer don't tell me what i should do. and I didn't touch the packaging things. eclipse worked well. suddenly it works weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up your project in Eclipse:
 1. Select your project in Project Explorer window
 2. From upper menu select Project -> Clean

Comment: I do it. but doesn't work. when i click java file in src folder on eclipse. eclipse still show me pop up "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError"

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest version of lombok from given link

Step 1: Download
https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.22/lombok-1.18.22.jar

Step 2: run the below command:

```
java -jar lombok-1.18.22.jar
```

Step 3: Specify the Eclipse path in the Installer Dialogue box

Step 4: Restart your IDE

Comment: This question is now 8 years old,  now i am full of hope that some day all my open question will be answered .

Answer (score 0):

Check if there in sts lombok is showing or not.
The path to see :
[1]: Help->About Spring Tool Suite
Mainly this type of error happened when you don't have set up of lombok in that workspace.
Download lombok from:
visit https://projectlombok.org/download