# calling wsdl based webservice from within alfresco

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, alfresco, spring-ws

i followed this article: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

so i have:

- HelloWorld http://pastebin.com/BJ3QA7pR
- HelloWorldImpl http://pastebin.com/RM5SBZ5C
- HelloWorldPublisher http://pastebin.com/H525WevK

which serves as the endpoint.

on the other side i have the client which i generated with wsimport:

- HelloWorld http://pastebin.com/g07H1exf
- HelloWorldImplService http://pastebin.com/f0YWMiYt

this runs fine in eclispe without alfresco being involved. however, i want to call the webservice from alfresco (from java backed web script for example)

i tried to copy the client side stuff to my amp file and calling it from a webscript but it fails!

`Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl does not implement the requested interface javax.wsdl.extensions.AttributeExtensible`

- Webscript http://pastebin.com/7JksRdtU

1 - is there a more elegant way to configure the access to the wsdl by defining a spring bean (spring-ws) or such

2 - why is it not working? full trace: http://pastebin.com/ak1qzygA

using alfresco community 5.0.a

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror . Dependancy jar issue?

Comment: i removed axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar from the lib directory - now it works ... but that is very strange to me.

Comment: Maybe there were conflicts with other wsdl4j.jar; the axis-wsdl4j jar picked on priority over the other. With axiswsdl4j jar gone things work now??

Comment: maybe. yes, its working with the axis wsdl jar gone

Comment: OK. let me just update it as an answer which could help others.

Comment: reported the issue at alfresco jira and fix is going to be in the next release https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-21093

Answer (score 1):

You will see IncompatibleClassChangeError usually when the dependancy/library jar has changed. Hence the method/code dependant on the library has to be recompiled against the changes.

Guessing the problem here has much to do with some dependancy jar being mispicked or an older version of jar present or one jar prioritized over the other. A look into the jars containing 'com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl' class in your classpath should be of some help.