# deploying Rest Jersey war file on tomcat

Tags: java, json, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to develope an Music Rest API, it works fine in local but after i deploying (exported that project as War file)& deployed on running Tomcat 7.0;

### after hitting an api url got below response:

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider and com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$Wadl disagree on InnerClasses attribute
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1106)
    java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1142)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

please anybody help me on this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Recompile the code with new libraries because "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError" error telling that some code use old library, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) and try again