# simple scala program gives Error: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, scala, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford's topic modelling toolkit

This is a simple scala program running on eclipse

Why do i keep getting this error  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class`

```
import scalanlp.io._;

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("added value"+c);

    val pubmed = CSVFile("pubmed-oa-subset.csv");

    println("Success: " + pubmed.data.size + " records");


  }
}
```

Full error here

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at scalanlp.io.CSVFile$.CSVFileAsParcel(CSVFile.scala:73)
    at Main$.main(t1.scala:27)
    at Main.main(t1.scala)
```

Comment: Problem appears to be on `CSVFile.scala:73`, can you show that?

Comment: @Danielson http://pastebin.com/dMsXsGBP

Comment: That is the input .csv file, dont know what you mean by "can you show `CSVFile.scala:73`"

Comment: While Transferring RNA is interesting, I'll read it later... That's not what I meant, though. You are showing the Main class, which calls `CSVFile`, I suspect the problem is on the 73th line of `CSVFile` (the class)

Comment: @Danielson Apologies, I'm a scala newbie, here is the source code of that file https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/1574270/

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: @wolfgang have you tried my answer?

Comment: @Danielson Hi Daniel, yes, my system has a small issue right now. i'll check and let you know very shortly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code supplied is correct... The problem is (most probably) a Scala version problem. The jar is compiled with Scala 2.8 (5 years ago), as quote from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/:

> TMT was written during 2009-10 in what is now a quite old version of
>   Scala, using a linear algebra library that is also no longer
>   developed. Some people still use it and find it a friendly piece of
>   software for LDA and Labeled LDA models, and more power to you, but at
>   this point we really can't offer any support or fix any problems.
>   Sorry about that.

The `IncompatibleClassChangeError` as described here [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1980452/928952), is due to a binary incompatibility. So the only option is to install an old version of Scala, preferable 2.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Danielson, This is the modified program with the output http://pastebin.com/P40rgVEa

Comment: @Danierlson I'm running the latest Java SE7  Do you have any other ideas why i'm finding this error?  library: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/tmt-0.4.0.jar dataset http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/examples/pubmed-oa-subset.csv  source code -> same as question

Comment: No, you didn't do anything wrong... I'm questioning Scala version... Since the project has been abandoned since 2010 (`TMT was written during 2009-10 in what is now a quite old version of Scala` from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/) , a lot of things have been happened (without backwards compatibility support, which is why I returned to Java). I know some major stuff happened between 2.8.0 and 2.10... (I can't install Scala < 2.10 in Scala IDE...)