# WildFly deploying

Tags: war, web-deployment, wildfly

When deploy application server WildFly 8.1.0, the following error occurs .

```
Thu Oct 01 13:31:07 GMT+300 2015
Failed to enable rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.IdleTimeoutHandler$1 with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

And only on one machine to the other all right and runs deploying and enable it. What could be the reason of it?

[server.log](http://pastebin.com/mQFMEsQk)

Comment: Please post server.log that shows full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the program you are deploying throws an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`. Causes for that error are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror). You should try to follow these steps:

1. Undeploy the old build
2. Clean the build
3. Stop Wildfly
4. Delete all temporary sources
5. Start WildFly
6. Build the application
7. Deploy the build

Answer (score 0):

```
Error getting reflective information for class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.IdleTimeoutHandler$1 with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.rest-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

This means, somehow, there is some Jetty class. IT really smells when in a deployment made for WildFly or any JEE compliant server in general, there is a class from package org.eclipse.jetty*.

Please try removing that dependency. I hope you're using JAX-RS for your REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss here the right Jboss-deplyoment-structure.xml