# Getting InvocationTargetException while making REST call to Spark 1.5.2

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

```
Problem accessing /api/v1/applications/Kafka_Window/2/jobs. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:728)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:657)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:264)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    ... 33 more
</pre>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:728)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:657)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:264)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I read about it found that this can be because of my java version. I am using 1.7 to build spark with maven 3.3.9.
I am hitting `http://<<myIP>>:4040/api/v1/applications/[appID]/jobs`

I have taken reference from [Monitoring and Instrumentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: yeah it does. May be I will get back here after some of real deep digging.