# Inject DAO into Restlet Resource class

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, restlet

I have this class with a method that returns String:

```
package com.fwd.pmap.service.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.fwd.pmap.util.EntityManagerUtil;

public class PMAPMatrixDAOImpl implements PMAPMatrixDAO
{
    private EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

    public String findPMAP(int campaignID, String staffCategory, int ispPlanID)
    {
        String pmapPlan = "";

        // If any of the mandatory fields is empty, return empty string
        if(campaignID == 0 || staffCategory.isEmpty() || ispPlanID == 0)
            return "Make sure all parameters are supplied";

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT P.PlanName FROM ClientPMAP P, PMAPMatrix M "
                + "WHERE P.ID = M.ClientPMAPID AND "
                + "M.campaign_id = :campaignID AND "
                + "M.StaffCategoryID = (SELECT ID FROM StaffCategory WHERE Name = :staffCat) AND "
                + "M.isp_plan_id = :planID AND "
                + "M.PreEx IS NULL";

        pmapPlan = (String) entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery)
                .setParameter("campaignID", campaignID)
                .setParameter("staffCat", staffCategory)
                .setParameter("planID", ispPlanID)
                .getSingleResult();

        return pmapPlan;
    }
}
```

Application

```
package com.fwd.pmap.service.web;

import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class EmployerApplication extends Application
{
    /**
     * Creates a root Restlet that will receive all incoming calls.
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        //http://localhost:9090/fwd-PMAP/pmap/campaign/1/staffCat/EXA1(A)/isp/10
        router.attach("/pmap/campaign/{campaign}/staffCat/{staffCat}/isp/{isp}", EmployerResource.class);

        return router;
    }
}
```

Resource

```
package com.fwd.pmap.service.web;

import org.restlet.data.Reference;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

import com.fwd.pmap.service.dao.PMAPMatrixDAO;
import com.fwd.pmap.service.dao.PMAPMatrixDAOImpl;

public class EmployerResource extends ServerResource 
{
    PMAPMatrixDAO matrix = new PMAPMatrixDAOImpl();

    @Get
    public String represent()
    {
        String campaignID   = (String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("campaign");
        String ispID        = (String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("isp");
        String staffCat     = Reference.decode((String) this.getRequestAttributes().get("staffCat"));

        String tmp = "Campaign=[" + campaignID + "], Staff Cat=[" + staffCat + "], ISP=[" + ispID + "]";

        matrix.findPMAP(Integer.parseInt(campaignID), staffCat, Integer.parseInt(ispID));

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

If I don't include PMAPMatrixDAO classes in my resource file the program works fine and return the string as expect. However, if i include the DAO I got an error below:

```
13:16:39,987 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9090-1) Failed to define class org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle in Module "deployment.fwd-PMAP.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:484) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:206) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-3]
    at com.fwd.pmap.util.EntityManagerUtil.<clinit>(EntityManagerUtil.java:19) [classes:]
    at com.fwd.pmap.service.dao.PMAPMatrixDAOImpl.<init>(PMAPMatrixDAOImpl.java:9) [classes:]
    at com.fwd.pmap.service.web.EmployerResource.<init>(EmployerResource.java:12) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.create(Finder.java:148) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.create(Finder.java:176) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.find(Finder.java:193) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:219) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:75) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:385) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143) [org.restlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117) [org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.3.4.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
```

pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fwd</groupId>
    <artifactId>fwd-PMAP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>

        <restlet.version>2.3.4</restlet.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.1</jackson.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.5</groovy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3cp0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CSV file reader utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Copy POJO to POJO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Restlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

How should I access the DAO class within a webservice?

Comment: Could you also provide your `pom.xml` file? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my post to include pom file.Thanks, Thierry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After agonizing for 3 over weeks I finally figured it out, it's caused by version incompatibility!!!

EAP 6.4 is NOT compatible with JPA 2.1 so I have to downgrade. Below are the steps I've taken to resolve this:

1. Right click on Project > Properties > JPA > Change JPA Version (Select 2.0)
2. Downgrade Hibernate to `<hibernate.version>4.2.21.Final</hibernate.version>` in the POM file
3. Change the top of persistence file to version 2.0

> ```
> <persistence version="2.0"
>   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
> ```

4. Run maven clean install

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try to remove the Hibernate dependencies in the Maven local repository directly. And then reinstall dependencies using Maven...

See this question for more details:

- [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)

Comment: Not sure whether I understand you correctly but you are saying to delete the files in: C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository\org\hibernate ? After that I should do a maven clean install? Sorry, I am still new to all this.

Comment: Tried but error still won't go away. Tried creating a dummy DAO without entity manager and restlet works fine. The moment I include emf into the DAO, *BOOM*, error appears. How should I access the DB then, any idea?