# IncompatibleClassChangeError java8

Tags: java, java-8

I'm getting IncompatibleClassChangeError during runtime. I have not figured out why. Here is the log:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at com.EmailCreator.lambda$null$396(EmailCreator.java:214)
    at com.EmailCreator$$Lambda$248/280771231.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.util.Xml$Tag.child(Xml.java:194)
    at com.EmailCreator.lambda$sendSoapRequest$397(EmailCreator.java:212)
    at com.EmailCreator$$Lambda$246/488301663.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com..util.Xml$Tag.child(Xml.java:194)
    at com.EmailCreator.sendSoapRequest(EmailCreator.java:202)
    at com.EmailCreator.send(EmailCreator.java:175)
    at com.exacttarget.EmailSendQueue.accept(EmailSendQueue.java:24)
    at com.exacttarget.EmailSendQueue.accept(EmailSendQueue.java:12)
    at com.task.queue.AbstractQueue$ConsumerWrapper.consume(AbstractQueue.java:615)
    at com.task.queue.AbstractQueue$ConsumerWrapper.consume(AbstractQueue.java:602)
    at com.psddev.dari.util.AsyncConsumer.doTask(AsyncConsumer.java:113)
    at com.psddev.dari.util.Task.run(Task.java:493)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code:

```
private static class EmailReceiver {
    String email;
    String key;
    String list;

    public EmailReceiver(Subscriber subscriber, ExactTargetSubscriberList list) {
        this.email = subscriber.getEmail();
        this.key = subscriber.getState().getId().toString();
        this.list = list.getState().getId().toString();
    }
}
```

Line 214 in EmailCreator is like below subscribers.child("EmailAddress").text(receiver.email); from the below code.

```
        for (EmailReceiver receiver : receivers) {
            objects.child("Subscribers", subscribers -> {
                ETSoapBuilder.addNilFields(subscribers);
                subscribers.child("EmailAddress").text(receiver.email);
                subscribers.child("SubscriberKey").text(receiver.key);
                subscribers.child("Attributes", attributes -> {
                    attributes.child("Name").text("ContentID");
                    attributes.child("Value").text(email.getId().toString());
                });
                subscribers.child("Attributes", attributes -> {
                    attributes.child("Name").text("Hash");
                    attributes.child("Value").text(receiver.list);
                });
                subscribers.child("Attributes", attributes -> {
                    attributes.child("Name").text("SubscriberKey");
                    attributes.child("Value").text(receiver.key);
                });
                subscribers.child("Attributes", attributes -> {
                    attributes.child("Name").text("EmailAddress");
                    attributes.child("Value").text(receiver.email);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated !!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror ?

Comment: Hi, I did but none of that suggestions helps :-(