# Can't authentication with WSO2 IS on webapp

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to create authentication mechanism on WSO2 IS and I have a trouble as following :
- I implemented to remote_user as the below link and the result is OK. I can login and access WSO API from console

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/user-mgt/remote-user-api/4.2.X/

But When I tried on webpage , I can't authenticate to WSO IS. the following is my code for this :

```
public void init() throws AxisFault{
        userName = HDConstants.USER_NAME;
        password = HDConstants.PASSWORD;
        backEndServerURL = HDConstants.SERVER_URL;

    setKeyStore();
    configCtx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
}

public void setKeyStore() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", HDConstants.TRUST_STORE_PATH);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", HDConstants.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", HDConstants.TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
}

public boolean authenticateUser(String userName, String password) throws Exception {
    String serviceURL = null;
    ServiceClient client = null;
    Options option = null;
    boolean isAuthenticated = false;
    AuthenticationAdminStub authStub = null;

    serviceURL = backEndServerURL + "AuthenticationAdmin";
    authStub = new AuthenticationAdminStub(configCtx, serviceURL);
    client = authStub._getServiceClient();
    option = client.getOptions();
    option.setManageSession(true);
    option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, authCookie);
    isAuthenticated = authStub.login(userName, password, HDConstants.APP_ID);
    authCookie = (String) authStub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext()
            .getProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);
    System.out.println(" Auth Cookie ==== " + authCookie);
    return isAuthenticated;
}
`
```

and the in the controller I used below code to call authenticate method:

```
AuthenticationServiceClient authenticationServiceClient = new AuthenticationServiceClient();
           authenticationServiceClient.init();
           authenticationServiceClient.authenticateUser("admin", "admin");
```

But the result is not good. The system inform that :

```
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:688)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:124)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:887)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
at com.home.hduser.wsois.AuthenticationServiceClient.init(AuthenticationServiceClient.java:29)
```

I don't know why I can authenticate on console but can't on webapp

and the full trace error attached in the file below :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zEqmu0HBunSlp3X0dpWC1YU0E

I appreciate your help in this case.
Thanks

Comment: post your complete error trace.

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, I attached full error in the above link.

Comment: What is your IS version?

Comment: I'm using the last version of WSO IS (5.1.0)

Comment: as a work around deploy the webapp in WSO2 AS 5.3.0, remove this jar first: tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-api-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-catalina-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-catalina-ha-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-jdbc-7.0.47.jar
tomcat-juli-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-tribes-7.0.59.jar
tomcat-util-7.0.59.jar

Comment: I don't understand what y mentioned above. Currently, I am working around WSO2 IS 5.1.0.

Comment: WSO2 IS 5.1.0, it's not for app deployment, it's for security services. I  deployed the app that you created inside WSO2 Application Server, change the IP/port in SERVER_URL pointing to my WSO2 IS 5.1.0. After that I removed the jars and I can authenticate in the "WSO2 IS" using the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this dependency in pom.xml file, set provided scope:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api</artifactId>
        <version>${carbon.identity.version}</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

To remove the tomcat dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- org.wso2.carbon.identity:org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api:jar:4.5.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.user.core:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wso2.carbon:javax.cache.wso2:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-dbcp.wso2:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4.0.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.wso2:jdbc-pool:jar:7.0.34.wso2v2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:7.0.47:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections.wso2:commons-collections:jar:3.2.0.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon.identity:org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.common:jar:4.5.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.core:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wso2.orbit.com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.5.0.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:jar:3.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:jar:0.9.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.22:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.equinox:org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper:jar:1.1.0.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ha:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-tribes:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:7.0.59:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.core.common:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.registry.core:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io.wso2:commons-io:jar:2.0.0.wso2v2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:jar:1.3.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.registry.xboot:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.compass-project.wso2:compass:jar:2.0.1.wso2v2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.abdera.wso2:abdera:jar:1.0.0.wso2v3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi.wso2:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.9.0.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-pool.wso2:commons-pool:jar:1.5.6.wso2v1:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.wso2.carbon.identity:org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub:jar:4.5.4:provided
```

EDIT: I had to set IS_HOME path absolute.

[image]

EDIT 2: To use relative path:

This method return the path to the wso2carbon.jks file:

```
public String setKeyStorePath(){
    String path = System.getProperty("carbon.home") + File.separator +
            "repository" + File.separator + "resources" +
            File.separator + "security" +
            File.separator + "wso2carbon.jks";
    System.out.println("wso2carbon.jks path: " + path);
    return path;
}
```

Modify the setKeyStore to use setKeyStorePath()

```
public void setKeyStore() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", setKeyStorePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", HDConstants.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", HDConstants.TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge, But Currently I have a trouble relating to authentication. the exception is "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)" while I set trustStore, trustStorePassword as above code:

Comment: if the problem is related to the trust anchor it´s for the relative path in public static final String IS_HOME = ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator;

Comment: I tried to get the TRUST_STORE_PATH from resource folder of project with the below code but the result is the same.
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
     File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("wso2carbon.jks").getFile());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: no, I set the path absolute to try and it work. the problem now is with the relative path.

Comment: please check my second update. it work now with relative path :-D

Comment: Hi Jorge,
After login successfully, I tried to get userInformation from storageManager with below code : 
UserRealm realm = WSRealmBuilder.createWSRealm(serviceURL, authCookie, configCtx);
    UserStoreManager storeManager = realm.getUserStoreManager();

But I had exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/user/core/UserStoreException

Could y please help me in this case ?

Comment: I also post my issue on the below link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120408/cant-get-user-information-after-login-successfully-in-wso2-identity-server

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're deploying your webapp in IS itself. I can see a lot of jars are packed in your war file. Most of them are already available in IS server.

Above error can happen due to dependency conflicts. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) for more information.

To get rid of the error, you can try setting `<scope>provided</scope>` to dependencies which are already available in the server.

Comment: oh, I'm trying to building a gate way to help accessing from our client ---> my Gate --> IS . 
Supposing that when Our client use login function. We will call login method in my Gate and then it will redirect to authenticate function on IS.
I tried to add <scope>provided</scope> in my pom file but the result is the same before.

Comment: Could y please provide for me the right repository for wso2 is or edit pom file from my project  ?

Comment: `wso2-nexus` repo you have in pom is correct. To find which versions of jars IS has, you can look at `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/plugins/` directory.

Comment: I see what y mentioned. I wonder that our code is incorrect or wso2 version in m y pom is incorrect so it caused error which I mentioned above.

Comment: what is `my gate`? tomcat?

Comment: So, you get above error in tomcat/jetty? In that case, try setting `<scope>provided</scope>` in dependencies which are already available in tomcat/jetty. Ideally what we need is to get rid of all duplicate jars.

Comment: oh I'm trying to do  on Jetty now. I also add <scope> in dependencies as your suggestions but the result is the same. what do you think about my code ? maybe it has any problems ?

Comment: I don't think it's due to a code issue. There's a high chance that it's due to a jar that's bundled to your war file. I googled a bit and found there're 100s of issues reported about `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError on jetty`. Go through them carefully. I believe you'll find a solution.