# Can't get user information after login successfully in WSO2 Identity server

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-identity-server

After login successfully into WSO IS with service URL (https://localhost:9443/services/")

I tried to get User Information as below :

```
 try {
                UserRealm realm = WSRealmBuilder.createWSRealm(serviceURL, authCookie, configCtx);

                UserStoreManager storeManager = realm.getUserStoreManager();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But I had exception relating to this as below image. I can't get any info.

[image]

I tried and found out that the main error is I can't create ConfixContext with the following code :

```
configCtx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
```

I also read about ConfigContext in the below link and tried with other methods in this link but I can't create configContext.
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/context/ConfigurationContextFactory.html

I appreciate your help in this case.
Thanks

Comment: with the code you provided the error that I found is this: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>

Comment: I see exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/um/ws/api/WSRealmBuilder the system couldn't find WSRealmBuilder class :( I don't know which version of WSO2 IS that I should use in this case ???

Comment: I use WSO2 IS 5.1.0 and I don't see this error NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: oh yes, I also use WSO 5.1.0. how do y think about version of wso2 in pom file in my project ?

Comment: I found out that the main reason is creating ConfigContext. I updated my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your runtime doesnt have `org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreException` class. Therefore you can't identify the real exception.

For now, just use `Exception e` instead, and see if you can log the real exception.

Comment: When I use Exception e instead, the real exception is : 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/um/ws/api/WSRealmBuilder
 the system couldn't find WSRealmBuilder class  :(
I don't know which version of WSO2 IS that I should use in this case

Comment: I deployed on tomcat and call authentication to IS

Comment: Since you're not in a carbon (wso2) runtime, you can't depend on wso2 classes except for service stubs. So, use RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub. See https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/utils/RemoteUserManagerClient.java

Comment: Currently, I'm only using WSO IS, not  WSO API Manager

Comment: I just wanted to show you how `RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub` is used. Ignore apim stuff.

Comment: Yes, I see your idea and I am also following it.

Comment: You don't need `UserRealm` and `UserStoreManager` then.

Comment: No, we need UserRealm and UserStoreManager for other actions but I still can't get now

Comment: You can only use service stubs in a non-carbon environment. What do you need them for?

Comment: I want to create a gate way to connecting between our client and IS System

Comment: I found out that the main reason is creating ConfigContext. I updated my question above

Comment: What is the error? Why do you need ConfigContext here?

Comment: oh, after login successfully, we have session and then base on session and configContext we can get Userrealm, UserStorage :
UserRealm realm = WSRealmBuilder.createWSRealm(SERVER_URL, cookie, configContext);

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your requirement. Why do you need `Userrealm, UserStorage` ? What are the information you need?

Comment: I need get user info, create role, create user and using some action which listed in the below link :
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs

Comment: You can do all of them with just `RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub`

Comment: your idea is using the below link : 
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/utils/RemoteUserManagerClient.java
 
and I need to use WSO API Manager , right ?

Comment: No you don't need any apim stuff. Just use stub.

Comment: Do y have any document or sample or tutorial for this ?

Comment: oh, I tried as your suggestion but has the same result when I had exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/um/ws/api/stub/RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub

It seems to be the causing error is relating to ConfigurationContext which I posted above :(

Comment: You need stub jar in your runtime.

Comment: which lib I need to include in pom file ?

Comment: this one. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/master/service-stubs/identity/org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub

Comment: oh.  I really added this lib into my pom file before. 
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>

Comment: remove `<scope>provided</scope>` part, if you have set it