# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter is hazardous

Tags: android

Before Updating my libraries my code worked fine. I updated libraries to support some new functionalities.The new functionalities work well, but when I test the old ones it crashes with the following error message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.siemens.solidedge.viewer, PID: 2917
                  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter is hazardous (/data/user/0/com.siemens.solidedge.viewer/cache/slice-android-support-v13_0d236b8e445f6b717cc6b3d71f12228242900e27-classes.dex at compile time, /data/user/0/com.siemens.solidedge.viewer/cache/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-25.0.0_4b8934deabed056f9d3bb10bda50dc400f9b3a59-classes.dex at runtime): Virtual method count off: 20 vs 21
                  Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter; (Compile time):
                   Static fields:
                    I POSITION_NONE
                    I POSITION_UNCHANGED
                   Instance fields:
                    Landroid/database/DataSetObservable; mObservable
                   Direct methods:
                    <init>()V
                   Virtual methods:
                    destroyItem(Landroid/view/View;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    destroyItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    finishUpdate(Landroid/view/View;)V
                    finishUpdate(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)V
                    getCount()I
                    getItemPosition(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
                    getPageTitle(I)Ljava/lang/CharSequence;
                    getPageWidth(I)F
                    instantiateItem(Landroid/view/View;I)Ljava/lang/Object;
                    instantiateItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;I)Ljava/lang/Object;
                    isViewFromObject(Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
                    notifyDataSetChanged()V
                    registerDataSetObserver(Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
                    restoreState(Landroid/os/Parcelable;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
                    saveState()Landroid/os/Parcelable;
                    setPrimaryItem(Landroid/view/View;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    setPrimaryItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    startUpdate(Landroid/view/View;)V
                    startUpdate(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)V
                    unregisterDataSetObserver(Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
                  Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter; (Runtime):
                   Static fields:
                    I POSITION_NONE
                    I POSITION_UNCHANGED
                   Instance fields:
                    Landroid/database/DataSetObservable; mObservable
                    Landroid/database/DataSetObserver; mViewPagerObserver
                   Direct methods:
                    <init>()V
                   Virtual methods:
                    destroyItem(Landroid/view/View;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    destroyItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    finishUpdate(Landroid/view/View;)V
                    finishUpdate(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)V
                    getCount()I
                    getItemPosition(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
                    getPageTitle(I)Ljava/lang/CharSequence;
                    getPageWidth(I)F
                    instantiateItem(Landroid/view/View;I)Ljava/lang/Object;
                    instantiateItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;I)Ljava/lang/Object;
                    isViewFromObject(Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
                    notifyDataSetChanged()V
                    registerDataSetObserver(Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
                    restoreState(Landroid/os/Parcelable;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
                    saveState()Landroid/os/Parcelable;
                    setPrimaryItem(Landroid/view/View;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    setPrimaryItem(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
                    setViewPagerObserver(Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
                    startUpdate(Landroid/view/View;)V
                    startUpdate(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)V
                    unregisterDataSetObserver(Landroid/database/DataSetObserver;)V
                   (declaration of 'android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter' appears in /data/data/com.siemens.solidedge.viewer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-android-support-v13_0d236b8e445f6b717cc6b3d71f12228242900e27-classes.dex)
                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: First question that should be asked is how did you include the library and what version did you include?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) will help.