# IncompatibleClassChangeError while deploying to eclipse tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jax-rs

I am trying to build a RESTfull service for excel type file download service. But when I try to deploy it to tomcat 9. I am getting the error of IncompatibleClassChangeError

The stacktrace is as followed : -

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2267)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
```

And my pom.xml is

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
```

I was able to deploy sucessfully until I added apache.poi dependency.

What might be wrong, as I read some where to increase tomcat size to 1Gb, but it did  not help.Please help someone, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two versions of the same library in your tomcat server?

[What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)

As there says, **Recompile the client code against the new library, and you should be good to go.**