# How can I fix java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java

Please help me about the error Exception in thread "main":

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at classifier1.Classifier1.main(Classifier1.java:159) C:\Users\almustafa\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1"
```

When I decompile Quick Rules classifer from jar, copy the code into NetBeans, and then write the declaration

```
QuickRules qr = new QuickRules();
```

the given error appears. How can I fix it please?

Comment: when extract source code of Quick rules classifier (Fuzzy rough set rule induction ) from jar by jd decompiler and then copy the result code in netbeans ide as class such as                                                                                                                                                                                              QuickRules qr=new QuickRules() ; will appear this error when class defintion how can fix it

Comment: You haven't provided enough details to be sure, but it seems likely that the QuickRules jar is in your classpath along with your decompiled and modified source.  Some of the other classes in that jar rely on the QuickRules class and you have modified it in an incompatible way.

Comment: See also [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1980452/2402272)