# Multi-feature Instant App crash issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-instant-apps

I am newbie to Instant app in android and following below link for reference:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#6

Installable apk and instant app with single feature is working fine.

But when I am trying to run Multi- feature instant app it's getting crash(Following step - 7 from the above link).

**Crash Report:**

```
 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bhaveshdesai.topekaapk, PID: 17609
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of android.support.v4.app.Fragment is hazardous (/data/app/com.bhaveshdesai.topekaapk-PhiyPZ303gxpikP7GugKyA==/oat/x86/split_topekaui.odex at compile time, /data/app/com.bhaveshdesai.topekaapk-PhiyPZ303gxpikP7GugKyA==/oat/x86/base.odex at runtime): Virtual method count off: 111 vs 150
    Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment; (Compile time):
    Static fields:
     I ACTIVITY_CREATED
     I CREATED
     I INITIALIZING
     I RESUMED
     I STARTED
     I STOPPED
     .....
```

**Feature Gradle File:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':topeka-base')
}
```

**App Gradle File:**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
android {
    baseFeature = true

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "25.4.0"
    espressoVersion = "2.2.2"
    androidTestVersion = "0.5"
    hamcrestVersion = "1.3"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
}

dependencies {
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    api "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    api "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:${espressoVersion}"
    testApi "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"

    androidTestApi("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${espressoVersion}") {
        exclude module: "espresso-idling-resource"
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    androidTestApi("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:${espressoVersion}") {
        exclude module: "espresso-core"
        exclude module: "recyclerview-v7"
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    androidTestApi("com.android.support.test:rules:${androidTestVersion}") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    androidTestApi("com.android.support.test:runner:${androidTestVersion}") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    androidTestApi "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}"

    feature project(":topekaui")
    application project(":topekaapk")
}
```

Please help me to solve this crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much try i found the problem.

Problem is due to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

After change `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment` its working.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. Can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 2):

`IncompatibleClassChangeError` typically happens when you make an incompatible binary  change to the library and don’t recompile the client code. See [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) (but this might not be the real cause of your issue)

After what step are you getting the crash?

However, what I can see right now is that your Feature gradle file has the following dependency `implementation project(':topeka-base')`, when it should contain `api project(':topeka-base')` instead. (assuming that your Feature gradle = topeka-ui gradle)

> topeka-ui/build.gradle
>
> Replace all pre-generated dependencies with the
>   following dependency:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     api project(':topeka-base')
> }
> ```

Please double check the codelab instructions to make sure you didn’t miss any steps.

Comment: I have changed `implementation project(':topeka-base')` to `api project(':topeka-base')`, but it gives same error.