# Hibernate MAPPING error with persistence class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hello everyone I am making a web-app and having some problems. I am sharing my codes as well as problems.

and here is my dao

```
package service;

import java.util.List;

import com.blog.mapperclass.UserData;

public interface UserService {
    public void addUser(UserData data);
    //public List <UserData> getAllUsers();
}
```

this is my DAO implementation

```
package com.blog.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.blog.mapperclass.UserData;


import service.UserService;
@Component
public class Usersdao implements UserService{


    SessionFactory session= new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    @Override
    public void addUser(UserData data) {
        Session ses=session.openSession();
        ses.beginTransaction();
        ses.save(data);
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("user added");
    }

}
```

my request mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/submit")
public String showSubmit(@ModelAttribute UserData data){

    dao.addUser(data);

    return "submit";
}
```

my cfg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8086/blog</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

          <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <mapping class="com.blog.mapperclass.UserData"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is the error

```
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.blog.mapperclass.UserData"/>
```

and when I use :

```
SessionFactory session= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

it gives  error

```
Failed to instantiate [com.blog.dao.Usersdao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

And all my jars are updated

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Please tell me the some solution for the problem I am newbie.

P.S : here is my pojo class

```
   package com.blog.mapperclass;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Component
public class UserData {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String user_id;
    @Column
    private String name;


    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String phone;

    @Column
    private int roll_id;

    public UserData(String user_id, String name, String password, String email, String phone, int roll_id) {
        super();
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.roll_id = roll_id;
    }

    public UserData(){}

    public UserData(String name, String password, String email, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public UserData(String user_id, String name, String password, String email, String phone) {
        super();
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


}
```

and my sql table :

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6yEd.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: SessionFactory session= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();  I think this line is give the IncompitableClassChange error but why?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and read the Spring documentation on how to integrate Hibernate/JPA, and how to use declarative transactions, because you have it all wrong.