# What causes an IncompatibleClassChangeError when calling methods via JNI?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a native application that launches a JVM and interacts with it through the JNI API.
The native application constructs a (complex) JVM object and passes it as parameter in a method call.
The problem is that in some cases, on determinate inputs, the JVM crashes during the execution of the method with:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

I learned that this exception is thrown by the JVM when some incompatible binary changes has been made to a class used by a client that is not aware of the changes. However, I don't see how this could happen: in my case the JVM has only one fat jar in the classpath. I can't find duplicate classes in it, and the client code is always compiled to produce the fat jar.

On "[What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)" I found that there is another potential reason: a method called via JNI with objects of the wrong type, e.g. in the wrong order. So, I added dynamic checks with [`IsInstanceOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#IsInstanceOf) to check the type of any object passed to the JVM. Unfortunately, all the checks succeed.

How can I debug this? The exception has no message (e.g. no message like "Expected non-static field ChildClass.message"). This may hint that it's a problem caused by the JNI, and not by the "more common" case of an incompatible binary change in a library.

I tried `-verbose:class` but I don't see anything strange in the log. The last loaded class seems a common Scala lambda function, nothing strange:

```
[Loaded a.b.c.FastPrettyPrinter$$$Lambda$457/868352876 from a.b.c.FastPrettyPrinter$]
```

Is there an *exhaustive* list, or explanation, of what might cause an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` when calling JVM methods *via the JNI*?

Comment: Try also `-Xcheck:jni`

Comment: I'm trying `-Xcheck:jni`, but the execution becomes so slow that in 1h the program has not yet reached the point where it usually raises the exception.