# IncompatibleClassChangeError on Junit 4?

Tags: java, junit4

I'm trying to run a simple test on my test file to see if it works before I test anything else. But, I'm receiving initialization error whenever I try running the test. I have no idea what initialization error could be. Please help me.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class RoundTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    fail("not yet implemented");
}
}
```

Here is the trace.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.isPre4Test(JUnit3Builder.java:17)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:10)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
   at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)

Comment: The problem is not with the java code snippet that you posted, but with how you have set up your project (Eclipse). So nobody here can help you unless you describe that setup.