# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError at DotenvPropertyLoader.java:11

Tags: java, gradle

I updated `spring-dotenv` to 2.5.3 from 1.0.0 like below `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.3'
}
```

then, I execute `./gradlew build` happened `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError at DotenvPropertyLoader.java:11
```

Why caused this error?

I have seen other answers like below. But I can't solve this problem.
[What causes java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror)

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I edited `build.gradle` like below.

```
// before
implementation ('me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.3')
// after
api ('me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:2.5.3')
```

but, I don't know why this solved it.

edit) I completely resolve this issue.

My application is multi module project.

moduleA use [`java-dotenv`](https://github.com/cdimascio/java-dotenv).
moduleB use [`spring-dotenv`](https://github.com/paulschwarz/spring-dotenv)

But, `java-dotenv` is deprecated , use `dotenv-java`.
I think `java-dotenv` and `dotenv-java` are same code strucuture.
if Both library are used together , occur IncompatibleClassChangeError.