# What are the steps to Bind Xmpp-plugin with Jmeter without getting the login no response exception

Tags: jmeter, xmpp, jmeter-plugins

**I have already did what the BlazeMeter guide said** and made a scenario the **Xmpp server is connecting** but when I reach the **Login I get the exception No response**.
I have already searched and saw what people said and did and so I tried to **build the plugin project with maven and got the jmeter-xmpp-plugin 1.5.1 jar file**,
then I replaced the old jar (which I downloaded using the plugin manager in jmeter) in the "lib/ext" folder with it, but another exception got caught which is :

> "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection, but interface was expected
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPConnection.setUpConnection(JMeterXMPPConnection.java:91) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPConnection.getConnection(JMeterXMPPConnection.java:83) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPSampler.getXMPPConnection(JMeterXMPPSampler.java:81) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPSampler.sample(JMeterXMPPSampler.java:38) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]  "

I do not know if any steps were missed or mistakes were made but I need some guidance through or steps to follow.

**I want to State that ->**
my real problem is the login No Response Exception that is :

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: null
> at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:191) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
> at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:175) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
> at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(XMPPConnection.java:535) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
> at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.login(XMPPTCPConnection.java:260) ~[smack-tcp-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.actions.Login.perform(Login.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.JMeterXMPPSampler.sample(JMeterXMPPSampler.java:57) [jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.2]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]

Comment: have you considered Tsung which is an alternative to JMeter for XMPP testing?

Answer (score 0):

Building a single .jar containing the plugin only might be not the best idea as you may create yourself a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) due to API mismatch between the plugin and its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

So I would recommend

1. Installing clean latest version of JMeter which is [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) as of now
2. Installing clean latest version of [XMPP Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/XMPPSampler.md) which is 1.5.1 as of now using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image]

   and at least this [IncompatibleClassChangeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) issue will go away.

Comment: Okay thank you ,but then i will face the No response exception again at login sampler , have you got any idea on how to fix that error?